# Will my digital ocean ip change if I phoenix my instance?

Tags: digital-ocean, prudentia

If I run a phoenix command on prudentia using digital-ocean, [the prudentia documentation](https://github.com/StarterSquad/prudentia) says:

> phoenix: shortcut for stop -> destroy -> create -> start -> provision (citing phoenix server Martin Fowler's article)

I know that if I destroy an instance on digital ocean and create a new one it will probably have another IP address, which would be problematic. I'd like to be sure before doing something rash…

Comment: In retrospect maybe I should have asked this on Server Fault… I can't find a way to move it over there. In any case I find it hard to assess where development stops and where operations starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prudentia will make sure that the instance retains its IP even upon recreation.

In this case most of the work is done by the Digital Ocean API. When phoenixing a Digital Ocean droplet Prudentia will use the *rebuild* api (search for it in here https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v1/droplets/) that states:

> This method allows you to reinstall a droplet with a default image. This is useful if you want to start again but retain the same IP address for your droplet.